# Can I access the end from only an iterator?

Tags: c++, qt, iterator

I have an iterator into a QByteArray which is passed to a function as:

```
MyData getNext(const QByteArray::const_iterator &it) {
    // calculate N
    if(end_of_array >= it + N)
        // process N bytes
}
```

I need to know if there are at least N bytes left in the array. Can I access the array object or the end from this passed iterator?

Comment: I do not think you will be able to do this without another iterator(the end iterator) or the container itself.

Comment: @NathanOliver Is there a way to add N to the iterator and see if it fails ... without trouble?

Comment: It behaves like a standard iterator i do not believe so.

Comment: @NathanOliver Thank you much. So that leaves me three options: 1) iterate over the next N items and it it fails, deal with that, 2) pass the array object, or 3) pass the needed end. I suppose 3 is best, unless there is any other idea.

Comment: It really depends on what you are doing.  When I see `getNext` I expect to get an iterator that is one more than what I pass in.  If that is all you are doing then you can just do that and leave it to the call site to check if it hit the `end` or not.  If you are doing something else then I would suggest changing the interface.

Comment: Iterators work in pairs; a pair of iterators defines a range. So, yes, your option 3 is the right way to go. Option 1 cannot work unless qt's iterators offer more than the standard iterators do.

Comment: @NathanOliver I am iterating over bytes, but `getNext` will attempt to process from 1 up to 4 bytes in each call. Since it is an array of bytes, and I can increment the iterator (right) can't I add N? Then check something?

Comment: Then you are going to need a range to check and make sure you do not go past the end.

Comment: @NathanOliver Okay. Very good. I'll pass the end. Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `QByteArray::const_iterator` is [just a typedef](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/corelib/tools/qbytearray.h?h=5.7&line=L401#n401) from `const char *` , it is impossible to retrieve the original `QByteArray` object without further context.

You cannot reconstruct an `end()` iterator either for exactly the same reason, at least without deeper knowledge of the data contained in the object. For example, if the data in a QByteArray is a null-terminated string you could look for `\0`, for example using [strlen](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strlen). Do note that `QByteaArray::end()` will point *beyond* that, since the null-terminator is part of the data it contains.

Obviously it is better to either pass a const reference to the `QByteArray` object along with the iterator (or an end iterator).

Comment: Thanks for a detailed and complete explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The `getNext` API is broken. You need to fix it to take a pair of iterators: a range. There's no other fix.